# c# Timezones question

Tags: c#, timezone

I implemented a country/region/city database for my site. Each city has a timezoneoffset stored as Varchar(32) in the format -06:00 , +09:00 etc. Now I'm not quite sure how to convert my UTC times which are stored in the database with those specific offsets. I know it's possible to convert using TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById but that's not possible with the 'semi numeric' values I have.

Does anyone have an idea on how to go around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/1583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got offsets, then you want `DateTimeOffset` - you don't really need a time zone. On the other hand, you should be aware that what you've got won't *accurately* reflect local time, because a single offset is inadequate for most places due to daylight saving time.

I would suggest you store an *actual* time zone ID... and if you *definitely* want to store a single offset instead, I suggest you store the number of minutes in an integer field - there's no point in introducing a string representation which you just have to parse again.

Comment: It was a little extra work but worth it I guess. I now added a new table with TimeZone Id's and connected them to the User record instead of City. Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone()` for this:

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("MyId", TimeSpan.FromHours(-6), "Somewhere", "Somewhere");
DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, targetTimeZone);
```

Comment: If you know the amount of time to add, why bother with a time zone at all? Either use `DateTimeOffset`, or `DateTime.AddHours`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: afaik when you use DateTimeOffset the passed DateTime and the utc offset have to match - so you couldn't create a Utc date time and pass in a different offset. But yes, `DateTime.AddHours()` is probably the easiest for OP. Sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees ;-)

Comment: No, a DateTime doesn't *have* a UTC offset in it. It's effectively timezone-less... calling ToUniversalTime or ToLocalTime assumes the system time zone, but that's not part of the value.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are right of course - the problem is just with the specific constructor I used for testing `DateTimeOffset` which validates the offset by comparing with `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(datetime)` - this just makes it awkward to work with unless you pass in ticks.

Comment: Ick, I wasn't aware of that constructor problem... that's nasty :( Dates and times are a bit of a mess...